# AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'aggregate_select'

Tags: python, django, pyodbc

I am writing a small script in Django. It is based on the Command class for execution by cron. I am using pyodbc with MS-SQL.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Sends email notifications'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        all_open_port = MyEmailModel.objects.using('emaildb').filter(u_sentinstant__gte=datetime.date.today())

        for p in all_open_port:
            self.stdout.write(p.u_sentinstant)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Successfully finished.'))
```

I alwas get this error, when the QuerySet is evaluated:

> AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'aggregate_select'

I am unable to solve this as the code is identical to the docs...

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\CarrierExchange\cusnotifier\management\commands\sendnotifications.py", line 12, in handle
    for p in all_open_port:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 824, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\compiler.py", line 204, in as_sql
    self._fix_aggregates()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\compiler.py", line 180, in _fix_aggregates
    for alias, aggregate in self.query.aggregate_select.items():
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'aggregate_select'
```

Comment: I believe you need to indent everything after `class ...`

Comment: Post the full traceback. The code you have posted does not contain `aggregate_select`, so the bug is triggered somewhere else in your app.

Comment: Hi, I posted my Traceback. The code has indent after class but it was removed when I pasted it at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in latest pyodbc / django-pyodbc:
https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/pull/146/files

Replacing "aggregate_select" with "annotation_select" in "lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\compiler.py" fixes the problem.